# std::exception.what() returns unexpected value on clang and gcc, but not on VS11

Tags: c++, exception, typeinfo

The contents of the C string returned by std::exception.what() and its derived classes is implementation defined, but clang, gcc, and Visual Studio return C strings that indicate the name of the exception class. But when I run the following code on clang 3.2, gcc 4.7, and Visual Studio 2012 I get strange results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    try {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    } catch (std::exception e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    try {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    } catch (std::bad_alloc e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With clang and gcc the output is

```
std::exception
std::bad_alloc
```

With VS11 the output is

```
bad allocation
bad allocation
```

My understanding is that clang and gcc implement exception::what() something like so

```
const char* exception::what() const
{
    return __typename_demangle(typeid(*this).name());
}
```

and that all derived classes use this implementation of the what() method. If I replace **e.what()** with **typeid(e).name()** in the above code then clang and gcc output

```
St9exception
St9bad_alloc
```

and VS11 outputs

```
class std::exception
class std::bad_alloc
```

I don't understand why the typeid isn't std::bad_alloc for both catch blocks. This behavior appears to cause the what() method to return the wrong value. Microsoft must have created different, trivial implementations of what() for all of the classes derived from std::exception, so VS11 does not suffer from this issue.

Comment: Try to catch exceptions by reference.

Comment: That fixed it and it answers the question. By catching the exception by value I was unwittingly converting the std::bad_alloc to a std::exception and making it lose its bad_allocness. It's interesting that VS11 still managed to return "bad allocation" in both cases. Anyway, if you answer the question I will accept it.

Comment: The phenomenon you are seeing is called "object slicing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this output because in the first case you create a new `std::exception` object, and in the second - new `std::bad_alloc` object. Instead of this you should catch exceptions by reference. The following code should show the difference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        // std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo(const Foo&)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo(const Foo&)" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Foo()
    {

    }

    virtual std::string what() const
    {
        return "what: Foo";
    }
};

class Bar: public Foo
{
public:
    Bar()
    {
        // std::cout << "Bar()" << std::endl;
    }

    Bar(const Bar&)
    {
        std::cout << "Bar(const Bar&)" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string what() const
    {
        return "what: Bar";
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw Bar();
    }
    catch(Foo f)
    {
        std::cout << f.what() << std::endl;
    }

    try
    {
        throw Bar();
    }
    catch(const Foo& f)
    {
        std::cout << f.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Foo(const Foo&)
what: Foo
what: Bar
```

<strike>But I don't have VS11, so I can't tell you, why is VS produces such an output. It will be nice if someone would clarify this.</strike>

Thanks to @BoPersson:

> The different message in the OP's case is because VC++ implements
>   what() by storing the message text in the exception base class. Other
>   implementations do not.

Comment: The different message in the OP's case is because VC++ implements `what()` by storing the message text in the `exception` base class. Other implementations do not.